# COMInterop - System cannot find file - IDE only

Tags: com, vb6, com-interop

I've an old VB6 program which I have haven't used for several months. The program references numerous C# assemblies (.NetFramework 4.8). Running the programs as binaries, it all works fine.

I have opened the VB6 ide to step some of my code and I am now encountering an automation error "The system cannot find the file specified." (Err 80070002) when trying to instantiate one of the COM Interop classes. This didn't used to happen.

```
Private Sub InitMessageStore()

    Dim l_oBusFactory As IfxBusService.BusFactory <= COM Interop reference

    Set l_oBusFactory = New IfxBusService.BusFactory <= ERROR here
    l_oBusFactory.InitialiseMessageStore GetConnection(m_oIfxsys.Dbase.Database.Definition)

End Sub
```

The COM Interop decls

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IBusFactory))]
[Guid("200C6C26-6881-4CB5-A8E7-E0E5532D6D5F")]
public class BusFactory : IBusFactory


[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[Guid("5531BD20-2C7B-452B-A7D7-2D05E39EB83E")]
public interface IBusFactory
```

I have rechecked the registry registrations for the  above ... the salient one being

[image]

and the file is in the folder location as specified in the registry.

I'm using Win10 Version 10.0.19044 Build 19044. I'm running everything as administrator. I have DEP switched to essential Windows programs and services only.

As I said above, everything works fine when run as binaries, but, to me, it looks like the OS is stopping the VB6 ide from loading a COM Interop assembly.

Any suggestions as to how I can get stepping through (but not necessarily into) my COM Interop code working again.

Comment: 0x80070002 is not usually returned by COM, but by components themselves. Check the component isn't itself try to load something. You can use Process Monitor tool from sysinternals to determine the files being sought for.

Comment: Thx vm. Always get a bit overwhelmed by ProcMon! ... what am I looking for ... I can see it reading the registry entry apparently successfully ... and then a load of SUCCESS/NAME NOT FOUND.    ....  obviously it works as pure binaries/.assemblies ....

Comment: You may need to copy the .net dll(s) to the VB6 folder, eg `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98` (or on a 64bit system, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98`)

Comment: @MarkL: for that I have a folder _(usually C:\DLL)_ on my dev machine and have that added to my `%PATH%`. This makes the act of keeping track of all DLLs and copying them over easier than navigating to VB's folder.

Answer (score 4):

In the end, I missed that there were 2 entries under the InprocServer32, one of which pointed to the correct file (1.0.0.0), but the other one (5.80.0.111 - which is actually the version no of our com binaries) didn't point to a file:///, but rather the pure .net assembly. Once I deleted the incorrect one, it all started working ok.

Still not sure where the wrong one came from!

[image]